# Insert ... on duplicate key update nothing using MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicate-data

My problem is that I have multiple unique keys on a table.

1. Insert ignore is not an option because it suppresses the errors.
2. MySQL has no support for any type of conditionals outside a statement (ex. if (cond) then insert else don't insert)
3. Stored procedures are not an option (the only place I can use the if/else statements)
4. On duplicate key might update a key with a new value, but I want the unique keys not to change in case one fails the unique constraint.

So the only option would be on duplicate just don't update anything. Is there any way I can achieve this? Or are there any other options?

Comment: Why are stored procedures not an option?

Comment: and why  on duplicate key might update a key with a new value?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a duplicate key? Do you need to know that there was a conflict?

Comment: @doublesharp If there is a duplicate key dont do nothing ... But i need to know if there was any other conflict except duplicate (ex. fk constraint).

Comment: @JohnWoo Thats the problem , i simply can't leave the update stmt empty. I need to pass some attribute that has to change.

Comment: @TudorTudor See my answer - you can just set a column value to the existing value, foreign key contraints will bubble up unlike `IGNORE` but no values will change on conflict.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to not actually do anything, just set a column value to the existing value. Other conflicts such as foreign key constraints will bubble up, unlike using the `IGNORE` keyword, but no values will change on conflict.

```
INSERT INTO table (value1, value2) VALUES ('1', '2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value1 = value1;
```

If you want to ensure that no valid data changes in the event of a conflict, you can add a column with arbitrary data in it to the table, and use that for the `UPDATE` statement.

A third option if you wish to keep all logic in your application and not in the database is to run a `SELECT` statement first to inspect potential conflicts before running your `INSERT/UDPATE` statement.

Although ruled out for your scenario, a stored procedure would also be able to provide this logic in a single database call.

Comment: How do i know that value 2 is the duplicate one ? If value 2 is dupliate is ok to update it , but dont update value 1 if value 2 is duplicate. If a unique constrain fails dont update any of the unique attributes

Comment: You can choose a field without a unique constraint for the `UPDATE`, or if you really want to make sure no important fields change, add another column with bunk data and use that in your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: yea was thinking of adding an extra null attribute, but thought there might be another solution. Hate this mysql limitations.

Comment: To be fair, this kind of logic *is* supported by MySQL, you just have to use a stored procedure.

Comment: It gives alot more overhead to keep track of alot of code on the db side . Especally when you have to keep track of alot of triggers / events/ routines . I droped all of them. Prefer to change the db design and keep more of the logic on the app layer .

Comment: I'm saying that because once i had to implement some oo concepts into mysql triggers . It was a nightmere .

Comment: In that case you could always run a `SELECT` first to check for duplicate data, and then follow with the `INSERT`. Not as efficient, but it keeps the logic in your app.

Comment: Please add the comment answeres to the final answer so i can validate it.

Answer (score -2):

Found another option in case someone stumbles across this issue.

If your table has an autoincremented primary key , you can update the pk like this :

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer got negative rating? This looks fine? thanks.

Comment: @Will59
It only works when inserting a single record, which is not usually the case when you're using `insert into... on duplicate key`