# Select without duplicate values in one column

Tags: mysql

My construction:

```
INSERT INTO ... ( SELECT ... FROM .. JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ... )
```

Short description: I'm using Select to insert data from 2 tables (using JOIN) to another table. The result of Select is something like (after order by):

```
col_a  |  col_b  |  col_c |        col_d

1111       44         xxx            yyy
1111       66         xxx            yyy
2222       12         aaa            bbb
3333       55         ccc            ddd
3333       68         xxx            yyy
```

If the row is duplicated (col_c) i want to insert to my table first matched row.

Example of result should be like this:

```
col_a  |  col_b  |  col_c |        col_d

1111       44         xxx            yyy
2222       12         aaa            bbb
3333       55         ccc            ddd
```

Comment: Please add the query like you already have.... on which column do you want to order by? And you only want to check on duplicate in col_c?

Comment: Use insert .. on duplicate like explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041023/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-nothing-using-mysql/13041065#13041065)

Answer (score 2):

Use the GROUP BY function

```
(SELECT ... FROM .. JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ... GROUP BY [col_c])
```

Comment: GROUP BY is executing before ORDER BY .. I want to first ORDER my result and then eliminate duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. I create `unique key` for the col in table. After that `INSERT IGNORE` is everyhing what I need :)